# OpenCV Error: imread() doesn't load my image

Tags: android-studio, opencv, machine-learning, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm writing an Android Application that allows the user to take a picture of a digit and then return the digit on the screen. I'm writing in C++ in Android Studio and I use the library OpenCV.

I load in the image:

```
cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Cornee\\Downloads\\OpenCVApp\\test.jpg",0);
```

Then I check if it worked with:

```
if(image.empty()) {
    std::string x = "Picture is not loaded!";
    return env->NewStringUTF(x.c_str());
}
```

When I run the application it returns the 'Picture is not loaded'. I tried to paste the pictures in multiple directories. Also I tried to hardcode the links, like I did in the code given above.

The whole code:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject
Java_com_example_cornee_opencv_MainActivity_testImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {

    // Load SVM classifier
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::StatModel::load<cv::ml::SVM>("classifier.yml");

    // read image file (grayscale)
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Cornee\\Downloads\\OpenCVApp\\test.jpg",0);

    // check if image is empty
    if(image.empty()) {
        std::string x = "Picture is not loaded!";
        return env->NewStringUTF(x.c_str());
    } else {
        // convert 2d to 1d
        cv::Mat one = image.clone().reshape(1,1);
        one.convertTo(one, CV_32F);

        try{
            float predicted = svm->predict(one);
            std::ostringstream ss;
            ss << predicted;
            std::string s(ss.str());
            return env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
        }catch(cv::Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Even my classifier does not load correctly. So I think there's something wrong with the localization of my files

Comment: Does the `cv::imread` actually succeed? You never seem to test the results and happily go using them. Since this message comes from [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L1049) test, it seems that you're trying to reshape an empty image. | What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: I made an if-statement and the 'two' variable is empty. So it doesn't load. I tried hardcoding the link and I pasted the 'test.img' in multiple directories but it does not seem to work

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path? Can you open and read the file using `fstream`? Does the classifier model load correctly?

Comment: Anyway, I'd suggest to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44486471/edit) your question and update it based on what you find -- e.g. we now know the problem is in the image not loading, so the title is quite misleading.  Or even start a new question.

Comment: I edited my question. Also I tried to check whether the classifier is getting loaded with if(svm == NULL). It returned with NULL so the classifier model doesn't load correctly. Lastly, I tried to open the file with fstream (also absolute and dynamic) and it also returns empty. So I think, globally, there is something wrong with locating the files.

This is the way I have my files organized: https://i.gyazo.com/fa80f2a70f8b231e712e05905e35a345.png